# Writing a full-line accepted from standard-input to a file with low-level C i/o

Tags: c, low-level, low-level-io, low-level-code

I am writing a program that concatenates a line input from standard-input with a seperate file, and writes the combined text to an output file.  For some reason when I type a full line of text into standard input, only the first word before whitespace is being written.  What's wrong with my code?

Accepting from std-in and writing:

```
// check for stdinput flag
if(strcmp(argv[1], "-") == 0) // use standard-in for input file 1
        {
            printf("Type your text and then hit enter: ");
            p = fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);
            if (write(output_file, userInput, sizeof(p)) < 0)  // write stdin to output file
            {         
                perror(argv[4]);
                close(output_file);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
```

Further along in the program... writing the second file to output:

```
    else // open file2 and assign to file-handler, then output to file
    {
        if((input_file2 = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        {
            perror(argv[2]);
            close(output_file); // close the opened output file handler
            exit(1);
        }

        while((n = read(input_file2, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
        {
            if((write(output_file, buffer, n)) < 0)
            {
                perror(argv[3]);
                close(input_file2);
                close(output_file);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        close(input_file2);
    }
```

command line and output:

```
server1{user25}35: program - file2 outputfile

Type your text and then hit enter: THIS IS MY TEXT FROM STDIN

server1{user25}36: cat outputfile
THISthis is the text in file2

server1{user25}37:
```

Comment: It's considered bad style to mix low-level POSIX I/O functions (read(2), write(2)) with the C stdio function (fgets, fprintf,...). (If you mix those on the same open file, this actually is unlikely to give the results you expected because of stdio's buffering)

Comment: Apart from that, don't use read(2)/write(2) unless you know what you are doing. You must do a great deal of error checking, like for I/O errors or signals interrupting the call (EINTR).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first fragment, you output `sizeof(p)` characters which is `sizeof(char*)` (which on a 64-bit system would be 8 bytes). You need to change this to at least `strlen(p)` (obviously, after checking for an error and `NULL` return value).